# How can the SPICE password of a libvirt+kvm+qemu virtual machine be changed while the machine is running?

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, password, libvirt

I have a virtual machine that is running on a KVM+QEMU stack with libvirt. The VM is using a qxl or virtio display and has a spice graphics listening on a port.

I'd like to change the password (in SPICE they call it "ticket") used to access that machine from virt-manager or remote-viewer while the machine is running. The old password should be invalidated immediately and new SPICE connections should only be possible with the new password.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to change the SPICE access password without a stop/start of the VM, the VM must already be equipped with a password. SPICE passwords cannot be added/removed without a restart.

Under this prerequis, we have two options to achieve this:

### A: solution with virt-xml

Use the command `virt-xml [-c qemu+ssh://host/system] name-of-the-vm --edit all --graphics password=verys3cr3t --update`

### B: solution with virsh

1. `virsh [-c qemu+ssh://host/system] dumpxml --security-info name-of-the-vm > output.xml`
2. look for the block  `<graphics type='spice' port='5900' autoport='no' listen='0.0.0.0' passwd='testpass'>...</graphics>` and isolate it, throw the rest away, save the graphics XML block under `graphics.xml`
3. Change the `passwd` attribute to the new desired password
4. `virsh [-c qemu+ssh://host/system] update-device name-of-the-vm graphics.xml`